# Largest sub-array with no NaN

Tags: arrays, numpy, matrix, nan

Consider `(m,m)` arrays that have the property that all entries are `nan`'s after a row index `i`, and after a column index `j`. A typical example is

```
[[ 0.00528902  0.00202571  0.00339491         nan         nan]
 [ 0.00777443  0.00322426  0.00503715         nan         nan]
 [ 0.00699781  0.00185539  0.00433489         nan         nan]
 [ 0.00526394  0.00254923  0.0034802          nan         nan]
 [        nan         nan         nan         nan         nan]]
```

In this example `A[i,j]` is `nan` if either `i>3` or `j>2` but in general I only now that they exist but I'm not given their values (`3` and `2` in this example).

I would like to find the largest submatrix that contains no `nan`. In above example that would be

```
[[ 0.00528902  0.00202571  0.00339491 ]
 [ 0.00777443  0.00322426  0.00503715 ]
 [ 0.00699781  0.00185539  0.00433489 ]
 [ 0.00526394  0.00254923  0.0034802  ]]
```

In fact, `m` will be quite large so I'd need this to be very efficient (I have to do this for many `(m,m)` arrays,  and the sizes of the largest subarray containing no `nan` varies from array to array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think there is a tiny mistake in your question, you should have `i>3`, not `4`, no? I'll take the liberty of editing that.

So, what we have to do to find `i,j` is to get the index of the bottom right corner of the submatrix that you want. The most efficient way that comes to mind is to use the `where` function from numpy. Consider the following code snippet which uses your example numpy array:

```
import numpy as np


a=np.array([[ 0.00528902, 0.00202571,0.00339491, np.nan, np.nan],
    [ 0.00777443, 0.00322426  ,0.00503715, np.nan , np.nan],
    [ 0.00699781, 0.00185539  ,0.00433489, np.nan , np.nan],
    [ 0.00526394, 0.00254923  ,0.0034802 , np.nan , np.nan],
    [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan , np.nan]])

indexes=np.where(np.logical_not(np.isnan(a)))
print(indexes)
```

which produces the following output:

```
(array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]), array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]))
```

The first array in the output specifies row indexes, and the second one specifies column indexes where you have "non-nan" values.

So, we can clearly see that in your case, the `(i,j)` that you seek are  given by

```
i=indexes[0][-1];#in your case, this is 3
j=indexes[0][-1];#in your case, this is 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Taking full advantage of the structure of your arrays

- it suffices to scan the first row and the first column
- we can use bisection to locate the first nan
   for this we can use searchsorted using the facts that

  - nan sorts right of everything else
  - it does not matter that left of the last non-nan the line is
    not actually sorted because we only test against a single nan

.

```
>>> i = A.T[0].searchsorted(np.nan)
>>> j = A[0].searchsorted(np.nan)
>>> A[:i, :j]
array([[0.00528902, 0.00202571, 0.00339491],
       [0.00777443, 0.00322426, 0.00503715],
       [0.00699781, 0.00185539, 0.00433489],
       [0.00526394, 0.00254923, 0.0034802 ]])
```

Comment: Nice answer! I'm kind of suprised, although your answer is obviously a lot more efficient than mine, I was expecting np.where and also the masks in numpy to be more optimized than that. Turns out that for a numpy array of size (5000*5000), your code takes about 1e-5 seconds on average, while mine takes about 1e-1 seconds. Yeah, I think I'm expecting magic from parallelization.